# Why the device "/dev/video1" not shows?

Tags: linux, ubuntu, google-chrome, debian, ffmpeg

I'm trying to share my desktop via virtual webcam, but unfortunately the app cheese and google chrome and any app can't have access to this device "/dev/video1", the "/dev/video0" is the integrated webcam of my computer, "/dev/video1" is the virtual webcam where im tryng to share my desktop.

**This is my command**

```
ffmpeg -f x11grab -r 15 -s 1366x768 -i :0.0+0,0 -vcodec rawvideo -pix_fmt yuv420p -threads 0 -f v4l2 /dev/video1
```

then, when i test the integrated webcam "/dev/video0" with the command:

```
ffplay /dev/video0
```

All works fine, and all applications can access to my integrated camera.

**But when i test the virtual webcam "/dev/video1" with the command:**

```
ffplay /dev/video1
```

ffplay works fine, and show the desktop of my computer, but the applications like a cheese or google chrome or any app, cannot have access to the Virtual Webcam "/dev/video1", cheese or google chrome or any application only shows the integrated webcam.